# Add border to cartesianchart LiveCharts

Tags: winforms, livecharts

I want to add a border to a cartesianchart in LiveCharts for a c# winforms project

I've tried some extensive searching and examples on github but no hints.
There is a BorderBrush & BorderThickness in Base, but don't know how to set:

```
cartesianchart1.Base.BorderBrush
```

Current workaround is using the code below to draw a line and the min and max of both X & Y axis.

```
Sections = new SectionsCollection
{
    new AxisSection
    {
         Value = 0.25,
         StrokeThickness = 1,
         Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0))
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here the command to use:

```
        cartesianChart1.Base.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        cartesianChart1.Base.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1.0);
```

Here the result:

[image]

best regards